# Server Internal Error in google app engine using python

Tags: python, mysql

```
import webapp2
import mysql.connector

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        db=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="bsit",database="registration")
        mycursor=db.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("select * from student")
        result=mycursor.fetchall()
        self.response.write(str(result))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

**Internal Server Error**
*The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aaqib Nadeem\Desktop\db-test\main.py", line 6, in get
    db=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="bsit",database="registration")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 162, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 454, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 418, in _open_connection
    self._do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 141, in _do_handshake
    packet = self._socket.recv()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mysql\connector\network.py", line 255, in recv_plain
    errno=2055, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error:
```

Please provide a solution of this error

Comment: Where is your database located?  You are trying to reach it on localhost.  Is mysql deployed as part of the google app engine app?  I don't thats' possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use MySQL with Google App Engine. You can use [GAE Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction) instead.